Did AWS SNS support the FCM analytics label?
I've tried:
{
  "GCM":"{ \"fcmV1Message\": { \"title\":\"Test\", \"body\": \"Test\" },\"fcm_options\": {\"analytics_label\":\"TestLabel\"}}\" }"
}

Able to receive the push notification but the analytics label is not created.
AWS SNS documentation
FCM documentation
